# iOS record audio error

Tags: ios, audio, input, record, channel

I am developing ios app for recording video and audio.
I implemented the recording audio. But first I record video from camera, then if I am recording audio, I can't record audio.
I used follow code.
AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_StreamDescription, &mRecordFormat, &size);

Here I got error(couldn't get input channel).
After I started this app and record audio immediately, recording audio was successed.
But I recorded video from the camera, then recording audio was failed.
I couldn't this reason.
Please let me know the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide us with more code in the right format. Or post the solution if you got any.

Did you try to solve the problem with the [AV Foundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3)? With it you can get access to the video and audio stream and put them together.